# transistionend event not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have been struggling to get the css transitions to work with IE. For some reason, the transitionend event is fired in all browsers except for IE.
I have created a small example here where shows the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/c55f60as/

Here's the code which should be called when the transition ends:

```
$('.box-to-illuminate').mousedown(function () {         

        $(this).addClass('holding');                
        $(this).bind('transitionend', function () {
            $(this).off('transitionend');
            $(this).removeClass('holding');        
        }
    );        
});
```

In Chrome and in Firefox, the box changes back to yellow in the transitionend event. This is never called in IE10+11.

I would be very thankful if someone could solve the puzzle!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

3 years later...

I ran into this issue and it seems in IE 10/11, transitionend will not fire if the transition occurs on a 'display:none' element or a pseudoelement, such as :before.

In your jsfiddle, the transition is defined in .box-to-illuminate.holding:before. You could restructure your code to have the transition be defined on .box-to-illuminate. I generally found it easier to define

```
.box-to-illuminate {
    transition: transform 1.4s;
}

.box-to-illuminate.holding {
    transform: rotate(0);
}
```

Which will trigger a transitionend event on a non-pseudoelement, and the actual transform does "nothing".

Answer (score -1):

That's because [IE 9 and lower](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend#Specifications) doesn't support `'transitionend'`, but it does support `'change'`. Although note while IE does support the change event, it is [incomplete in IE9 and buggy in previous version](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/). Just note since IE 9- doesn't support `transitionend` in this case the functionality will be limited:

```
$(this).bind('change', function () {
    $(this).off('change');
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks, but the example doens't work with IE 10 and IE 11 either!

Comment: @HankRearden I've tested `transitionend` on IE 10 and Edge and it worked fine, are you sure you are not running in compatibility mode on a previous version of IE?

Comment: yes I am sure I am running IE11. 
If you run the example in Chrome you'll see that the color changes back to yellow after the transition. This is not the case with IE.

Answer (score -1):

For me works when I use `addEventListener("transitionend"`).
Neiher `"MSTransitionEnd"` nor `"transitionEnd"` works if binded with frameworks, so the result might depend on specific framework/verion